# Using an inline function and CTE in a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to use both an inline function and a CTE in a SQL query, and I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I can do one or the other, but not both.

For example (boiled down to the bare minimum of useless queries), I can do:

```
WITH
    FUNCTION f_test RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1;
    END;
SELECT
    f_test()
FROM
    dual;
```

and I can do this:

```
WITH cte_test AS (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        dual
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte_test
```

How can I have both the function as well as the CTE defined for the select statement? Basically I want to end up with something like:

```
SELECT f_test(), cte_test.* FROM cte_test
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is given in the [Oracle `SELECT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) which to combine your inline function and subquery factoring clause would be:

```sql
WITH
    FUNCTION f_test RETURN NUMBER IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1;
    END;
cte_test ( id ) AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT f_test(),
       c.*
FROM   cte_test c;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> F_TEST() | ID
> -------: | -:
>        1 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e90070bee4cb627e80c9d7598c1d389)*

Comment: Thanks! I would also like to note that I had to add a / to the end to get it to run properly (at least in sql developer), which isn't necessarily true of a select statement without the inline function.