# Include multiple inline functions and multiple CTEs in a WITH clause in a single query

Tags: sql, oracle, with-statement, oracle18c, inline-functions

*Oracle 18c:*

What is the syntax for including **multiple inline functions** and **multiple CTEs** in a WITH clause in a single query?

Function #1:

```
function fucntion1(num in number) return number
is
begin
    return num + 1;
end;
```

Function #2:

```
function fucntion2(num in number) return number
is
begin
    return num + 2;
end;
```

CTE #1:

```
cte as (select 1 from dual)
```

CTE #2:

```
cte2 as (select 2 from dual)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ever for a "what is the syntax for ..." questions, you should refer to the official documentation.

The [`SELECT` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) is

> #### query_block ::=
>
> [image: query_block syntax]
>
> #### with_clause ::=
>
> [image: with_clause syntax]
>
> #### plsql_declarations ::=
>
> [image: plsql_declarations]
>
> #### subquery_factoring_clause ::=
>
> [image: subquery_factoring_clause syntax]

The [PL/SQL function syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/function-declaration-and-definition.html#GUID-4E19FB09-46B5-4CE5-8A5B-CD815C29DA1C)

> #### function_definition ::=
>
> [image: function_definition syntax]
>
> #### body ::=
>
> [image: body syntax]

Therefore:

- A PL/SQL function's body must be terminated with a `;`.

  *(Note: this is a PLSQL statement terminator and not a separator in the `WITH` clause between PL/SQL function declarations as there is no separator character following PL/SQL function declarations.)*
- There is a `,` character between successive sub-query factoring clauses.
- The `SELECT` statement does not need a `;` or `/` statement terminator but it may be allowed/required/forbidden by the client application you are using to denote the termination of the statement.

  For example:

  - You can only pass a single statement via an OJDBC statement and, for this client, the statement terminator is forbidden.
  - In SQL Developer, when you are running a single statement then the trailing statement terminator is allowed but is optional.
  - In SQL Developer, when you are running a script then statement terminators are required between statements.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the syntax is:

- Use a semicolon at the end of each function, including the final function. (no backslash)
- Separate the CTEs with a comma.
- Edited: Don't include a final semicolon or backslash *in the WITH clause*.

---

```
with

function fucntion1(num in number) return number
is
begin
    return num + 1;
end;

function fucntion2(num in number) return number
is
begin
    return num + 2;
end;

cte as (select 1 from dual), 

cte2 as (select 2 from dual)

select
    fucntion1(1) as function_result
from
    cte
union all
select
    fucntion2(1)
from
    cte2

FUNCTION_RESULT
---------------
              2
              3
```

Related: [Using an inline function and CTE in a SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996526/using-an-inline-function-and-cte-in-a-sql-query)

Comment: While this is "nominally" correct it misses a lot of subtlety in why the syntax is required. A `;` after functions is not required by the `WITH` clause's syntax but is required to terminate a PL/SQL function (so must be present but not for the reasons implied by the answer). Similarly, "don't include a final semicolon or backslash." is both true and misleading as the `SELECT` statement does not require the trailing statement terminator but the client application may either forbid/allow/require it which means that if you omit the terminator then some clients may be fine and others complain.